# What, exactly, does aptitude's ?origin() search term match against?

Tags: aptitude

Because it doesn't seem to be the same string as is produced by the `%O` display format escape, nor the URL from `sources.list.d`.

In my case, I'm looking for packages which I installed from non-Ubuntu sources and the trouble I'm having can be seen in this example:

```
$ aptitude search --display-format '%v %p %O#' '?exact-name(syncthing)'
1.23.6         syncthing                            Syncthing:syncthing [amd64]         
$ aptitude search --display-format '%v %p %O#' '?exact-name(syncthing) !?origin(ubuntu)'
$ aptitude search --display-format '%v %p %O#' '?exact-name(syncthing) ?origin(ubuntu)'
1.23.6         syncthing                            Syncthing:syncthing [amd64]         
$
```

When the `?origin` term isn't included at all, SyncThing shows up with an origin that doesn't contain "ubuntu", so I expected it to remain when adding `!?origin(ubuntu)` (i.e. "must not come from an origin matching the pattern 'ubuntu'"). Instead, it disappears unless I change the term to require that it *does* come from an origin matching "ubuntu"!

Looking at the source list for the origin isn't enlightening, either:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/syncthing.list
deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/syncthing-release-key.gpg] https://apt.syncthing.net/ syncthing stable
```

This clearly isn't a case of just "all origins match 'ubuntu'", however — if I look at VS Code instead of SyncThing, it behaves as expected:

```
$ aptitude search --display-format '%v %p %O#' '?exact-name(code)'
1.81.0-1690980 code                                 code stable:stable [amd64]          
$ aptitude search --display-format '%v %p %O#' '?exact-name(code) !?origin(ubuntu)'
1.81.0-1690980 code                                 code stable:stable [amd64]          
$ aptitude search --display-format '%v %p %O#' '?exact-name(code) ?origin(ubuntu)'
$
```

So how does the `?origin` search term actually behave? What is it matching against?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `aptitude` search term `?origin` matches the `Origin` value in the repository's `Release` file.

For example, on a very basic install of 22.04 the output of `apt-cache policy` lists the following repositories.  In this output the search term `?origin` compares to the `o=` value, which is `Ubuntu` for all of the repositories on this machine.

```
root@ubuntu:~# apt-cache policy
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-updates,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-updates,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
```

Browsing the repository's Release file shows corresponding values.  E.g. http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/Release contains

```
Origin: Ubuntu
Label: Ubuntu
Suite: jammy
Version: 22.04
Codename: jammy
```

With `aptitude` you can search the available packages from this `Origin` with a command like

```
aptitude search "?origin(Ubuntu)"
```

You can search for "packages which I installed from non-Ubuntu sources".  The `?origin(.*)` search term can be added to avoid issues with packages that may not have any `origin`.

```
aptitude search "?and(?installed, ?not(?origin(Ubuntu)))"
or
aptitude search "?and(?installed, ?origin(.*), ?not(?origin(Ubuntu)))"
```

As a more complex example, one of my favorite commands is to find all packages with an update available from the official `Ubuntu` repositories (including `UbuntuESM`).

```
aptitude search "?and(?upgradable, ?narrow(?version(CANDIDATE), ?origin(^Ubuntu~(ESM~){0,1}$)))"
```

The origin name is particularly confusing because

- The search term `?origin` does not match the display format `%O` value, as noted in the original question.
- `apt_preferences` lets you specify an `origin`, but that `origin` matches the repository hostname.  E.g. `archive.ubuntu.com`.
- `unattended-upgrades` has configuration for `Allowed-Origins` that is really a combination of the repository values.

**syncthing**

If I add the `syncthing` repository then the `syncthing` package exists with both `Ubuntu` and `Syncthing` origins.

The output of `apt-cache policy` shows the following information about the repository.

```
 500 https://apt.syncthing.net syncthing/stable amd64 Packages
     release o=Syncthing,a=syncthing,n=debian,l=Syncthing,c=stable,b=amd64
     origin apt.syncthing.net
```

The output of `apt-cache policy syncthing` shows packages available from Syncthing and Ubuntu repositories.

```
root@ubuntu:~# apt-cache policy syncthing
syncthing:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.23.6
  Version table:
     1.23.6 500
        500 https://apt.syncthing.net syncthing/stable amd64 Packages
     1.23.5 500
        500 https://apt.syncthing.net syncthing/stable amd64 Packages
     1.18.0~ds1-3ubuntu0.2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages
     1.18.0~ds1-3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
```

An aptitude search like `?and(?origin(Ubuntu), ?exact-name(syncthing))` will match `syncthing` because there is a version of that package that matches.

Some tests I tried

```
root@ubuntu:~# aptitude search "?and(?origin(Ubuntu), ?exact-name(syncthing))" -F "%p,%m#,%O#" | column -t
syncthing,Syncthing  Release  Management  <release@syncthing.net>,Syncthing:syncthing  [amd64]

root@ubuntu:~# aptitude search "?any-version(?and(?origin(Ubuntu), ?exact-name(syncthing)))" -F "%p,%m#,%O#" | column -t
syncthing,Syncthing  Release  Management  <release@syncthing.net>,Syncthing:syncthing  [amd64]

root@ubuntu:~# aptitude search "?all-versions(?and(?origin(Ubuntu), ?exact-name(syncthing)))" -F "%p,%m#,%O#" | column -t
```

You can try to use search terms like `?narrow` to restrict to specific versions of packages.  This should show installed packages where the installed version has an Origin that is not `Ubuntu`.

```
aptitude search "?narrow(?version(CURRENT),?and(?origin(.*),?not(?origin(^Ubuntu))))"
```

**notes**

I wish I had a source I could reference.  This just information I have figured out in the past through testing.

Comment: Hmm. Digging in to my use case some more, the behavior I'm seeing doesn't seem to match your description. [Syncthing's Release file](https://apt.syncthing.net/dists/syncthing/Release) doesn't contain the string "ubuntu" at all, but matches `?origin(ubuntu)`. [VS Code's release file](https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/23.04/prod/dists/lunar/Release) *does* contain the string "ubuntu" — right in the Origin field, even — but matches the negated `!?origin(ubuntu)` instead. 

Comment: I tested with syncthing and I think because there is an official package in the Ubuntu repository you may be getting unexpected results.  I added some more notes about what I see.

Comment: Ah! Of course. Syncthing exists in the official repos, but Code does not, so Syncthing appears in the list of "has **any origin** that matches 'ubuntu'" but Code doesn't. I was conflating "Syncthing, the package" with "Syncthing, the repo/origin". Thanks again for your help!